# Bar plot of group means with lines of individual results overlaid

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

this is my first stack overflow post and I am a relatively new R user, so please go gently!

I have a data frame with three columns, a participant identifier, a condition (factor with 2 levels either Placebo or Experimental), and an outcome score.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Condition = c(rep("Placebo",10),rep("Experimental",10)), 
                  Outcome = rnorm(20,15,2), 
                  ID = factor(rep(1:10,2)))
```

I would like to construct a bar plot with two bars with the mean outcome score for each condition and the standard deviation as an error bar. I would like to then overlay lines connecting points for each participant's score in each condition. So the plot displays the individual response as well as the group mean.If it is also possible I would like to include an axis break.

I don't seem to be able to find any advice in other threads, apologies if I am repeating a question.

Many Thanks.

p.s. I realise that presenting data in this way will not be to everyones tastes. It is for a specific requirement!

Comment: I would guess providing some example data set and a link to a similar picture to your desired output will get you started

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) has good advice for creating nice questions. `dput()` is nice for sharing data, and if you find a suitable built-in dataset, do try to create a nice *minimal* example that has the necessary features.

Comment: See [Plotting means and error bars (ggplot2)](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
Is the below a suitable example of data:
dat <- data.frame(Condition = c(rep("Placebo",10),rep("Experimental",10)), Outcome = rnorm(20,15,2), ID = factor(rep(1:10,2)))

Comment: In general, with code, you should edit things into your question rather than leaving them in comments.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. I have managed to create the desired plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat.summ <- dat %>% group_by(Condition) %>%
  summarize(mean.outcome = mean(Outcome),
            sd.outcome = sd(Outcome))

ggplot(dat.summ, aes(x = Condition, y = mean.outcome)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean.outcome - sd.outcome,
                    ymax = mean.outcome + sd.outcome),
                color = "dodgerblue", width = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = Condition, y = Outcome),
            color = "firebrick", size = 1.2) +
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = Condition, y = Outcome, group = ID),
            color = "firebrick", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(dat$Outcome)))
```

[image]

Some people are better with ggplot's `stat` functions and arguments than I am and might do it differently. I prefer to just transform my data first.

Comment: Thanks very much. Very helpful. Is it possible to ass points at the end of the individual lines?

Comment: see edits. I added the points to the code but didn't update the pictures.

Answer (score 3):

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Condition = c(rep("Placebo",10),rep("Experimental",10)), 
                  Outcome = rnorm(20,15,2), 
                  ID = factor(rep(1:10,2)))

dat.w <- reshape(dat, direction = 'wide', idvar = 'ID', timevar = 'Condition')

means <- colMeans(dat.w[, 2:3])
sds <- apply(dat.w[, 2:3], 2, sd)
ci.l <- means - sds
ci.u <- means + sds
ci.width <- .25

bp  <- barplot(means, ylim = c(0,20))
segments(bp, ci.l, bp, ci.u)
segments(bp - ci.width, ci.u, bp + ci.width, ci.u)
segments(bp - ci.width, ci.l, bp + ci.width, ci.l)
segments(x0 = bp[1], x1 = bp[2], y0 = dat.w[, 2], y1 = dat.w[, 3], col = 1:10)
points(c(rep(bp[1], 10), rep(bp[2], 10)), dat$Outcome, col = 1:10, pch = 19)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using the transfomations inside `ggplot2`

```
ggplot(dat) + 
stat_summary(aes(x=Condition, y=Outcome, group=Condition), fun.y="mean", geom="bar") + 
stat_summary(aes(x=Condition, y=Outcome, group=Condition), fun.data="mean_se", geom="errorbar", col="green", width=.8, size=2) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Condition, y=Outcome, group=ID), col="red")
```

[image]